# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587 nodemailer NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to connect nodemailer to send mails to users after registration.
So I turned on IMAP in google settings, than I created app to generate password, and it all works with [this serivs](https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test). But when I try to connect mail service, I have this error

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
> errno: -111,
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 587,
> command: 'CONN'
> }

mail-service:

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
class MailService {
  constructor() {
    this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
      },
    });
  }
  async sendActicvationMail(to, link) {
    await this.transporter.sendMail({
      from: process.env.SMTP_USER,
      to,
      subject: "Mail activation " + process.env.API_URl,
      text: "",
      html: `
            <div>
              <h1>For activation click on link</h1>
              <a href="${link}">Click here !</a>
            </div>
          `,
    });
  }
}
export default new MailService();
```

Where I might made mistake ?
Thank you !

Comment: you are not getting environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniil

This code is working for me. But I configured "Sign in using app passwords" https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB, because  nodemailer needs an access connect to gmail. Next I changed process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD from gmail mail's password to "app's password for your device" - it looks like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx code.

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

class MailService {
    constructor() {
        dotenv.config();
        this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
            port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
            service: process.env.SMTP_SERVICE,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
                pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
            },
        });
    }

    async sendActivationMail(to, link) {
        await this.transporter.sendMail({
            from: process.env.SMTP_USER,
            to,
            subject: "Activation account" + process.env.API_URL,
            text: "",
            html: `
            <div>
                <h1>Activate your account, please</h1>
                <a href="${link}">${link} </a>
            </div>
            `
        });
    }
};
export default new MailService();
```