# Nodemailer won't send emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-modules, nodemailer

I have a bug related to Nodemailer v. 6.9.3. When I launch nodeJS localhost, then this appears:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

the code:

```
const nodeMailer = require('nodemailer')

const html = `
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Wordked!</p>
`;

async function main() {

    const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'lohproh38@gmail.com',
            pass: 'Good55555!'
        }
    })
    
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'lohproh38@gmail.com',
        to: 'holaves228@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Testing, testing, 123',
        html: html,
    })

    console.log("Message sent: " + info.messageId)
}

main()
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

I tried changing the version, rewriting the code and changing the gmail account, but nothing helped

Comment: Maybe your provider blocks outgoing emails?

Comment: Alose, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73699808/7353417

Comment: oh, yes, these are my real data, but I'm not worried because this is an old and unnecessary account for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
> ```

Your code tells the library to try to connect to an SMTP server running on the same computer as your app, on port 465.

It tries to do this and your computer rejects the connection.

This usually means that you are not running an SMTP server on that port.

You need to provide credentials to an actual SMTP server. The fact you mentioned GMail credentials suggests you are trying to connect to GMail's SMTP server.

GMail doesn't run their SMTP server on *your* computer. You need to put in the address of their server.

Answer (score 0):

The error is how you have created the transporter

```js
const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: 'localhost', <-- you can't use localhost here
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: { // <-- This credential must be authenticated from the service provider
        user: 'lohproh38@gmail.com', 
        pass: 'Good55555!'
    }
})
```

Try checking out some third-party service providers for easy integration.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too. Here is how I solved this:

This code works both on Mac and Windows:

```
const { AUTH_EMAIL, AUTH_PASS, SMTP_SERVER } = process.env

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: "www.example.com", // Add your domain (Without this it doesn't work on windows) 
    host: SMTP_SERVER, // Make sure to configure this properly in .env file, // example: mail.example.com

    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: AUTH_EMAIL,
        pass: AUTH_PASS,
    }
});

// test transporter 
transporter.verify((error, success) => {
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("Ready for sending mails");
        console.log(success);
    }
});
```